# Syntax for using a plugin's custom event method

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, click, jquery

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax to use when a plugin/widget requires using a custom 'event' method instead of the standard jQuery events.

The [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) doesn't support the `change` method, and instead provides a `click` event which is fired when a checkbox is checked or unchecked. I'm trying to use the syntax supplied in the widget's documentation for the `click` event so that I can replace several change functions including the one shown below, but I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax.  The structure for the `click` event is:

```
$("[name=Item]").on("multiselectclick", function (event, ui) {...});
```

I've tried inserting the function in between the curly brackets, and I've also tried `.on("multiselectclick", function () {...});` without success, so I'm assuming that I need to insert something here: `(event, ui)`

I've managed to get the functions partially working by using a slightly different method `$("[name=Item]").multiselect({ click: function (event, ui) {...}`, but I'd really like to understand how to use the plugin's custom event so that I can get the functions working properly. I posted a fiddle with a very simple example here http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/cZRy9/5/, and included notes to indicate what wasn't working properly.

One of the functions where I'm trying to replace a `change` event with the widget's `click` event:

```
$("[name=Item]").change(function(){
    $("#Styles1, #Styles2").hide();
    $(".accordion").accordion("option", "active", false);
    if( $("[name=Item]").val() === "Dresses"){
        $("#Styles1").show();
        $(".accordion").accordion("option", "active", 0);
        $('varItem').val('Dresses');
    }
    else {...} 
});
```

Comment: do you have multiple element's with same name= `Item` ?

Comment: using `click:function()..` property in options object is same as writing separate external `on` handler. Code should do same thing either way  assuming you have correct custom event name. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net showing problems

Comment: @MohammadAdil - No, in this document each select element has it's own name :-) I do occasionally use the same name for more than one element if only is visible at a time one (using 'display:none')

Comment: @charlietfl - I just created a fiddle with a very simple example, and included notes about the 2 things that weren't working jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/cZRy9/1/

Comment: @charlietfl - It took me a little while to get the script for the accordion working properly in the fiddle (the function hides the accordion and/or changes which section is active), so I just updated my fiddle to include the 3rd part of the function jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/cZRy9/5 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue about not hiding the `Styles` element when `dresses` is unchecked is straightforward. There is nothing in code to check state of the checkbox, only the value

Fix with:

```
if ((ui.value) === "Dresses" && ui.checked)
```

Using the `ui` object within a jQuery UI patterned widget is usually best source for your data or state , rather than using jQuery selector to look for the same thing.

I have never used this plugin, so to figure out what was available to me, I simply used `console.log(ui)` within the click handler so I could inspect the `ui` object to see what properties it contained, and found the `checked` property to add to above `if` conditional

If you do the same on a more complex widget like jQueryUI datepicker will see quite a significant number of `ui` properties , some of which are also method functions

DEMO (using custom event)

http://jsfiddle.net/cZRy9/2/

Comment: I guess I was on the right path when I used (ui.value) instead of the element's name ;-) Does this mean that I have to change the syntax for each part of the function? If so, can you clarify how I would know what/how to change? Also do you know if there's any documentation/tool which I can use to help me in rewriting the functions?

Comment: everything else in your code should work...not sure what you mean by "rewrite"

Comment: I just tried the rest of the function and you're right :-) Does that mean that the only thing I need to change is the IF statement - using 'if ((ui.value) === "Dresses" && ui.checked)' instead of 'if( $("[name=Item]").val() === "Dresses")'? Out of curiosity, is this generally true for other method functions as well?

Comment: yes to changing the `if`...not sure what you mean about other methods

Comment: I was referring to other custom 'event' methods (for this and/or other widgets/plugins)

Comment: typically yes when plugin gives access to events. Depends on author but nowadays is common practice. When choosing a plugin , after basic feature set, I always look for a) good documentation and b) good access to event callbacks

Comment: That's incredibly helpful because unfortunately none of the plugins that I've used address this in the documentation :-) Out of curiosity, would you mind explaining why the usual syntax of 'if( $("[name=Item]").val() === "Dresses")' often doesn't work with custom events? It would be great to understand the cause/principle so that I can better apply this to other situations :-)

Comment: `if( $("[name=Item]").val() === "Dresses")` should work fine as long as only one element in page with `name=item`.  But...requires a search to locate the element again...could just use `$(this).val()`. Main reason for using plugin defined object though is perhaps value isn;t set before the event is triggered, I doubt it, but if values are accessible within objects already defined by plugin is safer and more efficient

Comment: That makes a lot of sense :-) But for some reason it isn't working with this widget (which is why I've been so confused by all this ;-)) Here's a fiddle where I replaced the IF statement: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/9Y5jn/5/

Comment: OK... goes back to what I was saying about safer to use data provided by plugin. place this before `if`  ...`console.log( $("[name=Item]").val())` then look in browser console and check box on and off. Not clear to me why but when box is checked select has no value. Have t keep in mind a lot of manipulation goe on with plugins like these...thus using the plugin API as much as possible is best practice

Comment: Now I see what you were saying about the console.log. It shows the correct value when I use it with the standard event method, but when I switch to the custom method it requires 'console.log(ui.value)' to show a value.